# Find the image of the line under the linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

An example in my book states:

> A linear transformation $T$ has equations $x'=3x-y$ ,  $y'=x+y$ . Under $T$, find the image of the line with equation $y=2x-1$.

The solution then starts

> We need to write the equation of the image line in terms of $x'$ and $y'$.

They then set the $x'$, $y'$ vector equal to the transformation matrix multiplied by the $x, y$ vector and solve for $x$ and $y$. Which they then plug into the original equation of the line, and once it's in standard form, they switch $x'$ to $x$ and $y'$ to $y$.

Why are they doing this? I understand how to do the whole thing, but I don't understand why. Can we not just plug in the $x'$ into the $x$ and the $y'$ into the $y$. It seems to me like they are actually finding the inverse if they do as they did... What am I missing?

They then use these $x$ and $y$ to find the image of equations of circles, parabolas, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t simply “plug in the $x'$ into the $x$ and the $y'$ into the $y$.” You need to end up with an equation in the new (transformed) variables $x'$ and $y'$, but replacing $x$ with $3x-y$ doesn’t get you any closer to having that: the new variables still don’t appear anywhere in the expression. Moreover, making these substitutions doesn’t make algebraic sense: you can legitimately plug in *values* of $x$ and $y$ for these variables, but $x'$ and $y'$ aren’t values of these variables. Instead, you need to invert the transformation so that you have expressions for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$. You can then legitimately substitute those expressions for the variables $x$ and $y$ in the original equation.

This is really no different from what you learned to do in order to translate and/or scale the graph of a function of one variable. E.g., shifting the graph right by $2$ corresponds to adding $2$ to all of the $x$-coordinates of points on the graph, that is, it is accomplished by the transformation $x' = x +2$. However, to obtain the equation of the shifted graph, you had to replace $x$ by $x-2$ (really by $x'-2$), which is the inverse of the transformation. The reasoning is the same: $x$ is replaced by an expression that equals $x$, not by an expression that equals $x'$. Similarly, to scale the graph by a factor of $2$, you had to *divide* $x$ by $2$, again using the inverse transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

$2x’+2y’=8x$ and $3y’-x’=4y$. Use the fact that $4y=8x-4$ is also an equation of the line $y=2x-1$.

---

Since the question is to find the line image, not the equation of the line image you can also do it this way. Find two points lying on the line $y=2x-1$ e.g $A(0,-1)$ and $B(1,1)$. After that find images of $A’$ of $A$ and $B’$ of $B$. It is easy to compute and obtain $A’(1,-1)$, I let you find $B’$. Now the image of the given line is just the line $(A’B’)$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but could you please tell me why the textbook is doing it as they are instead of providing an alternative solution?

Comment: Do you know something about Matrix product and how it this related to affine transformation.

Comment: I don't know what an affine transformation is, but yes I do know about matrix product. As I said in the question, they find the transformation matrix and multiply it by the x y vector, then solve the x y vector, and plug those values into the equation of the line. I understand how they are doing it, but not why. As for your method of finding the equation of the line with points, it does not allow one to find the image of a circle or a parabola for example.

Comment: See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you mean by "... they switch $x′$ to $x$ and $y′$ to $y$.", as this is nonsensical if the equation is supposed to be given in the new coordinates $x'$ and $y'$.

Also the way seems rather cumbersome. A faster way could be

- Write down the transformation $\binom{x'}{y'} = \begin{pmatrix}3 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\binom{x}{y}$
- Write the line $y=2x-1$ in parametric form: $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{1}{2}t+\binom{0}{-1}$
- Apply the transformation to the line: 
  $$\binom{x'}{y'} = \begin{pmatrix}3 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\left( \binom{1}{2}t+\binom{0}{-1}\right) =\binom{1}{3}t+\binom{1}{-1}$$
- Eliminate $t$ using $x'= t+1 \Rightarrow t = x'-1$ and plug this into $y' =3t-1 \Rightarrow \boxed{y' =3x'-4}$

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I would've done. Just parametrize the line and solve. I'd like to understand what they're doing though...

Comment: They solve the coordinate transformation for $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{x(x',y')}{y(x',y')}$. By replacing $y=2x-1\Leftrightarrow y(x',y') = 2(x(x',y')) - 1$ and rearranging into the form $y' = ax' + b$ you get again the equation of the line in the new coordinates $x',y'$.